# Is there a way to make command text follow input?

Tags: java

Say i want to print a text prompt in java, and then get input from user from System.in. But another thread can write to System.out and "takes down" the input but the text prompt stays up, which is normal.

> Enter input here ->
>   `<waiting for input ...>`

But if a thread writes something the following occurs:

> Enter input here ->
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   Thread output here
>   ...
>   ...
>   `<Waits for input here>`

Is there any trick to "bind" the input with the prompt text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your system.outs into a logging class, and when you want to print something add it to a queue in the new logging class.

When ever you ask for user input, have it activate a lock in the logging class so anything in the queue doesn't get printed until the user input is submitted, then have all the output in the queue get printed.

This will result in all the output text being paused while input is coming in. It won't interrupt your input, so the input will be bound around the cursor, but you also won't get any output. Up to you if that's worth it.

Comment: Indeed, this is a more-detailed description of the wrapper concept I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if there is a pre-existing one, but I have not personally heard of any.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any trick to "bind" the input with the prompt text?

Nope. It's your code; it's up to you to cooperate with yourself. That could mean building (or finding a library which provides) a wrapper API around `System.(in|out)` so you don't have to worry about accidentally causing this issue. But no, there is no magical silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if any existing implementations exist but this task should be simple enough.

Make a class e.g  SyncConsole which synchronizes your prints and reads.

Basically have only SyncConsole singleton in your code that writes and reads to the io streams of the console.

Then your program can do something like

```
SyncConsole.readInput("Text to display");
SyncConsole.print("Text");
```

These calls can then be properly synchronized to suit your needs. E.g if some code requested input, buffer requests to print till the input has been received and so forth.

If you are familiar with concurrency in java this should be fairly simple to build and will give you the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MainDemo {

    public void queueExample() {

        Queue queue = new LinkedList();

        queue.add("Java");
        queue.add("DotNet");

        queue.offer("PHP");
        queue.offer("HTML");

        System.out.println("remove: " + queue.remove());
        System.out.println("element: " + queue.element());
        System.out.println("poll: " + queue.poll());
        System.out.println("peek: " + queue.peek());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainDemo().queueExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, but I'm not sure that's relevant?